# Unable to update Canvas on Drag with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following a sample code online [Demo](https://codepen.io/giladaya/pen/QdGLmZ) which I am trying to use on Reactjs. The goal is simple - to be able to select a boundary box and it will return the coordinates (x, y, height and width) of the box.

After porting over, it can return the coordinates of the x, y, 0, 0 on first mousedown. However, it is unable to draw the red boundary with a mouse drag and return the coordinates

I suspect the issue lies in the code for updateCanvas below. Anyone able to help on this. Thanks

**Rector.js**

```
import React from "react";

class Rector extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    width: 320,
    height: 200,
    strokeStyle: "#F00",
    lineWidth: 1,
    onSelected: () => {}
  };

  canvas = null;
  ctx = null;
  isDirty = false;
  isDrag = false;
  startX = -1;
  startY = -1;
  curX = -1;
  curY = -1;

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = this.props.strokeStyle;
    this.ctx.lineWidth = this.props.lineWidth;
    this.addMouseEvents();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.removeMouseEvents();
  }

  updateCanvas = () => {
    console.log("@this ", this);
    if (this.isDrag) {
      requestAnimationFrame(this.updateCanvas);
    }
    if (!this.isDirty) {
      console.log("dirty");
      return;
    }

    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.props.width, this.props.height);
    if (this.isDrag) {
      const rect = {
        x: this.startX,
        y: this.startY,
        w: this.curX - this.startX,
        h: this.curY - this.startY
      };
      this.ctx.strokeRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.w, rect.h);
    }
    this.isDirty = false;
  };

  addMouseEvents = () => {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.onMouseDown, false);
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", this.onMouseMove, false);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", this.onMouseUp, false);
  };
  removeMouseEvents = () => {
    document.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.onMouseDown, false);
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.onMouseMove, false);
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.onMouseUp, false);
  };

  onMouseDown = e => {
    this.isDrag = true;
    this.curX = this.startX = e.offsetX;
    this.curY = this.startY = e.offsetY;
    requestAnimationFrame(this.updateCanvas);
  };

  onMouseMove = e => {
    if (!this.isDrag) return;
    this.curX = e.offsetX;
    this.curY = e.offsetY;
    this.isDirty = true;
  };

  onMouseUp = e => {
    this.isDrag = false;
    this.isDirty = true;

    const rect = {
      x: Math.min(this.startX, this.curX),
      y: Math.min(this.startY, this.curY),
      w: Math.abs(e.offsetX - this.startX),
      h: Math.abs(e.offsetY - this.startY)
    };
    this.props.onSelected(rect);
  };

  render() {
    console.log("render");
    return (
      <canvas
        width={this.props.width}
        height={this.props.height}
        ref={c => {
          this.canvas = c;
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Rector;
```

**RectorPage.js**

```
import React from "react";

import Rector from "./Rector";

class RectorPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selected: false,
      x: -1,
      y: -1,
      w: -1,
      h: -1
    };
  }

  onSelected = rect => {
    console.log("@rect ", rect);
    this.setState({
      selected: true,
      ...rect
    });
  };

  getSelectionStr() {
    if (this.state.selected) {
      const state = this.state;
      return `x: ${state.x}, y: ${state.y}, w: ${state.w}, h: ${state.h}`;
    }
    return "No Selection";
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Rector width="640" height="480" onSelected={this.onSelected} />
        <div>{this.getSelectionStr()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default RectorPage;
```

Comment: Your `updateCanvas` code appears to be the same as the linked example. Can you please provide the code that you have changed and how you are calling this function?

Comment: @smashed-potatoes hi. i have provided the full code. I converted the functions to use arrow functions so no need to bind this

Answer (score 0):

I stopped the server and restarted it and it seems to be working now!